# Django: Adding user to groups in a signal

Tags: python, django

I created a signal which is supped to do 3 things:

1. Create a User
2. Create the Profile of said user
3. Add User to a Group

Using a signal, steps 1 and 2 work fine but I can't seem to add the user to a group (step 3).

```
# Signals
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  if created:
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    group = Group.objects.get(name='generics')
    instance.groups.add(group)
```

Did some debugging and found out that even if I comment out `Profile.objects.create(user=instance)` I still can't add any groups to `instance`.

Am I missing anything here? I'm not getting any errors.

**Edit 1:** This is a custom User model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
  first_name = None
  last_name = None

  class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'users'

  def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

I simply moved `first_name` and `last_name` to the `Profile` table. Didn't do anything else as you can see. Users and Profiles are successfully being created so this custom model works just fine.

Although unnecessary, I added `instance.save()` after adding the group but it still won't work. The admin shows no groups have been added and the the db table `core_user_groups` is still empty.

**Edit 2:** Add console test

Even more weird, I tried adding the group using `./manage.py shell` and it works fine.

```
>>> from core.models import User
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
>>> group = Group.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> group
<Group: generics>
>>> user = User.objects.get(pk=23)
>>> user
<User: sonic>
>>> user.groups.add(group)

# At this point I check the admin and the db and it worked. Hmmm....but how to do it within a signal...
```

Comment: Try to assign user to group as follows: `my_group = Group.objects.get(name='my_group_name') 
 my_group.user_set.add(instance)`

Comment: @bloodwithmilk I tried your suggestion but still nothing. Steps 1 and 2 work but not step 3.

Comment: your code should work, are you sure the signal is called? How do you verify that step 3 isn't working?

Comment: @dirkgroten Because when I check the admin and the db the table is empty.

Comment: When you create the user, are you doing `commit=False` perchance? Where is step 1 happening?

Comment: @ritlew Nope to your first question.

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- If your project is initialized from [Cookiecutter](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django)
- You have `groups` in your `users/admin.py`module listed in your `Permission fieldset`

When you use `post_save` signal to add users to groups

1. the user object is saved
2. the `post_save` signal is triggered to add the user to group(the user is added to group and saved to database)
3. the user group is cleared since you haven't chosen any group in the admin page(the users' group information is cleared)

A quick fix can be: delete `groups` from `UserAdmin.fieldsets` in the admin.py

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserListAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
         ...
        (_('Permissions'), {
            'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser'), # 'groups'
        }),
```

Comment: This solved for me

Comment: Great answer; exclude avoids having to list the fields you want to keep.

`exclude = ['groups']`

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to add some fields to default user model, you shouldn't inherit from abstract user. Better to use related models using one-to-one field

My suggestion is to remove custom class. And add relation between your profile and auth.User models.

Comment: I'm tempted to go with this if I can't get this right by tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to still be able to still have groups in admin, you could do the following:

```
def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
    super().save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
    group = Group.objects.get(name='generics')
    form.instance.groups.add(group)
```